# Is it possible for someone to buy a fighter jet?

Tags: fighter, aircraft-purchase

Yesterday I came across a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PHcdn8R4d4) of a person who purchased 3 [Harriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrier_Jump_Jet) ("Harrier Jump Jet").

This brought up the question of: assuming he/she has the capability of paying for the price, is it possible for a regular civilian to purchase a fighter jet?

The video did note that the person was a retired test pilot. Is that a reason why he was able to purchase the jet?

Comment: related [Which 2-seat 4th generation fighter/engine/configuration (de-militarized) would the best supersonic long-range civilian private transport?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/77152/which-2-seat-4th-generation-fighter-engine-configuration-de-militarized-would)

Comment: Highly related: [Can a civilian purchase a new (Not Retired) fighter jet?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/61728/can-a-civilian-purchase-a-new-not-retired-fighter-jet?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This is like a trading question. Purchasing is the easiest part because there are plenty of sellers with surplus military equipment. Your first difficulty could be payment, if your bank's jurisdiction regulates arms purchase. Importing it to your home county is yet another challenge, e.g. to clear the customs. And then finally it's the permit to operate, subject to aviation regulations. However, if you pick a jet trainer instead of a fighter, all of these would be a lot easier, and performance is similar.

Comment: Just type "jet fighters for sale" into your search engine, or look at the "warbirds" section of Trade-A-Plane - where you'll find 3 Harriers listed (price not shown), as well as a MiG-29 for $4.6 million, a MiG-21, MiG-17...